# how to attach wood shutters

Tags: siding, shutters

I have made board and batten shutters for the windows of my Vermont house. They are decorative, not functional. I need to know how to attach them to the house which has old siding made of wood covered with some sort of plastic/vinyl (1980s variety). What should I use to attach them?

Comment: What do you want the fasteners to look like? Almost anything that's corrosion-resistant and long enough to penetrate framing should do.

Answer (score 1):

use screws then putty and stain the screw holes. i would predrill the screw holes. thats the way new construction is done

Comment: This is very helpful, may I ask a couple of more questions?  Do I put the putty into the predrilled hole in the siding before inserting the screws? Should I counter sink the screws and then put putty over them? Thank you for your help.

Comment: they make a stain-able wood filler. if you go to lowes you may be able to get the putty in the same color you are going to stain it. predrill holes then put screw in. i say this to prevent cracking when you screw the borads.  since your screwing into wood wall it will be pretty easy. now if you are going into brick or something it gets more hectic. now i am saying stain because most people stain them. but if your just painting just predrill sink screw then fill with putty and paint/stain. not alot of weight but put a screw in each vertical board to prevent from warping

Comment: Good to know about how to prevent warping. Thanks also for stainable wood filler idea. I'm mostly worried about the hole in the siding, but maybe putty over the screw will take care of it?

Comment: ya you will never know the holes were there is you putty and stain the wholes right

Answer (score 0):

Another couple ideas for others would be using a bullet catch and clip that attaches to the back of the shutter allowing them to clip to the house.  There is also a cleate and anchor system that uses a few angled pieces of metal to hang the shutter (also invisible).